# SOLR faceted-search to return facet counts as with OR operator

Tags: solr, faceted-search, facet

I'll try first explain what I would like to achieve by using faceted-search in SOLR, before setting the question. Imagine I have a parameter for dog which is describing for what is dog suitable for and one dog can have multiple choices. Let's call it "housing". So dog is suitable for:

1. indoors
2. outdoors
3. children
4. old people
5. guarding.

So basically when I use faceted search on this parameter I get the results with my current database like this (url query `facet=true&facet.field=housing`):

indoors (74), outdoors(63), children(71), old people(65), guarding(31).

Now when I check the indoors parameter (url query `fq=housing:1&facet=true&facet.field=housing`) I get the results like this:

indoors (74), outdoors(53), children(60), old people(53), guarding(15).

It is showing me that if check next parameter "outdoors", there are 53 dog which are indoors AND outdoors. I would like to get the result, which would tell "How many dogs will be added to the result if I check next option". Because there can be dogs which are suitable for outdoors only. I would like to get results like this after checking first   "indoors" parameter:
indoors (74), outdoors(83), children(78), old people(79), guarding(75)
OR in other way
indoors (+0), outdoors(+9), children(+4), old people(+5), guarding(+1)

Is it something like this possible in SOLR faceted-search? Or am I using incorrect tool for achieving this. Because basically when I check "indoors" and "outdoors" I get the proper result count from the query (url query `fq=housing:(1 OR 2)&facet=true&facet.field=housing`). Just facet counts are not the ones I expected.

Comment: Didnt get the example complexly ? do you want to get the facet counts irrespective of the filter ???

Comment: I have figure out that only way (probably) to achieve what I want is to make another query just for facets like this fq=housing:(!(1))&facet=true&facet.field=housing&rows=0 which basically negates the original query. For more checked options (eg indoor and outdoor) I need query like that fq=housing:(!(1 OR 2))&facet=true&facet.field=housing&rows=0. Since there are more parameters I would need basically for every of them make this "negation" query to get the numbers, which does not really seem optimal to me :/

Comment: you can exclude the facets filters within the same query. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Tagging_and_excluding_Filters. you can also add alias to facet field so that you get both the included and excluded facets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you will need to use the [facet.query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.query_%3a_Arbitrary_Query_Faceting) parameter, which will allow you to specify a query that will only apply to the faceting results and not the main query.

> This param allows you to specify an arbitrary query in the Lucene default syntax to generate a facet count. By default, faceting returns a count of the unique terms for a "field", while facet.query allows you to determine counts for arbitrary terms or expressions.

In your case, I believe you will still return the facet counts for unique terms for a "field", but with some additional filters applied.

Comment: Wow that was an answer. Yes I am now able to return facet counts exactly in a way I need them.  I also need to mention I used Jayendra's way of excluding the facet filters within the same query and final query looks like this:
fq={!tag=dt}housing(1 OR 2)&facet=true&facet.query={!ex=dt}housing:(3 AND !(1 OR 2))
So when option "indoors" and "oudoors" is checked and I need to know how many additional results will be returned if third one is checked.

Answer (score 1):

I think next way should work:

```
fq={!tag=housing}housing:1&facet.field={!key=housing}housing&facet.field={!key=housing_ex ex=housing}housing
```

And you should get something like:

```
"facet_counts": {
  "facet_queries": {},
  "facet_fields": {
    "housing": [
      "1", 74,
      "2", 53,
      "3", 60,
      "4", 53,
      "5", 15
    ],
    "housing_ex": [
      "1", 74,
      "2", 63,
      "3", 71,
      "4", 65,
      "5", 31
    ]
  }
}
```

Then you should do: `housing_ex - housing`. And the result is:

```
1: +0
2: +10
3: +11
4: +12
5: +16
```

`numFound + housing_ex - housing`:

```
1: 74
2: 84
3: 85
4: 86
5: 90
```

`facet.query` is not suitable for a lot of facet values.

Answer (score 1):

append the parameter &rows=0

Comment: While this is not an answer to the question above, this will help you to lower the amount of time taken for the query to fetch initial facet results (to build the initial filters with) without losing too much performance. (as filter query results will be cached) +1 for giving me a good thought!